# Why the bars from second onward are shifting ahead on x axis?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, jqplot

I have this code for a chart I am working on:

```
plot = $.jqplot('SalesChart2',
            [
                [[1,5]],
                [[1,10]],
                [[1,15]],
                [[1,20]],
                [[2,25]],
                [[3,10]],
                [[4,10]],
                [[5, 6]]
            ]
            , {
                // Tell the plot to stack the bars.
                stackSeries: true,
                series: [
                                { label: 'Cash' },
                                { label: 'CreditCard' },
                                { label: 'DebitCard' },
                                { label: 'StoreCredit' },
                                { label: 'Discount', disableStack: true },
                                { label: 'AverageTransaction', xaxis: 'xaxis', yaxis: 'y2axis', disableStack: true },
                                { xaxis: 'xaxis', yaxis: 'y2axis', label: 'ItemsPerTransaction', disableStack: true },
                                { xaxis: 'xaxis', yaxis: 'y2axis', label: 'CustomerCount', disableStack: true }
                            ],
                animate: !$.jqplot.use_excanvas,
                seriesDefaults: {
                    renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
                    rendererOptions: {
                        highlightMouseDown: true,
                        barWidth: 50
                    },
                    pointLabels: { show: true }
                },
                axes: {
                    xaxis: {
                        renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                        ticks: [1,2,3,4,5]
                    },
                    yaxis: {
                        tickOptions: {
                            formatString: "$%'d"
                        }
                    },
                    y2axis: {
                        autoscale: true,
                        min: 0
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    show: true,
                    location: 'e',
                    placement: 'outside'
                },
                grid: {
                    drawGridlines: false
                }
            });
```

This renders as below:

[image: Chart for sales data]

The bars here are shifting a bit ahead from the point 2 on x axis. And for this reason, the last bar for 'Customer Count' is not visible.

Can someone please guide me for what's happening here?

Comment: Are you using the last version of JQPlot?

Comment: Have you tried lowering the `barWidth` property?

Comment: yes, but it doesn't work

Comment: This looks like a bug in jqplot.  `disableStack` was designed for combination bar/line plots, I've never seen it used for combo stack bar/regular bar plots.

Answer (score 0):

you should try a null barwidth to have the width computed automatically. 
And i think barmargin's default (10) is too high since you are near a 50 width.

Comment: Extremely bad results if I set barwidth to null